# Errors when converting MapInfo .tab to .dxf

Tags: mapinfo, ogr

I am trying to convert some MapInfo files to .dxf format using OGR2OGR using the following command:

```
OGR2OGR -f "DXF" "input.dxf" "output.TAB" -overwrite -skiperrors
```

When I run this I am getting a lot of errors which say "DXF layer does not support arbitrary field creation, field 'xref' not created".

**Can you not attach data to records in DXF files?**

I am also getting the error "No known way to write feature with geometry 'none'" and the same for "Multi Point".

**Which geometry types can DXF support?**

Update: In Mapbasic the Export command allows exporting to DXF, thereby negating the need to use OGR2OGR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can you not attach data to records in DXF files?

Not currently.  The author of the ogr dxf provider decided it was to much of a pain to handle attributes for dxfs (trying to find quote now)

> Which geometry types can DXF support?

The dxf driver page has more details: http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_dxf.html

Comment: So DXF *can* have data attached, but OGR just can't handle it? Good answer. Thanks!