# How to create a 3D DXF from ARCGEN with gdal ogr2ogr?

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, dxf

From ARCGEN (Esri ArcInfo Generate) I want to create a DXF with distinguishable layers:
[import_polz.pol](https://www.namotec.de/pub/import_polz.pol)

[image]

The transformation to a three-dimensional shapefile runs flawlessly with gdal ogr2ogr:

```
ogr2ogr  -f "ESRI Shapefile"  export_lin.shp  -nlt LINESTRING -dim 3  import_polz.pol; ogrinfo -so -al export_lin.shp
```

or

```
ogr2ogr  -f "ESRI Shapefile"  export_pol.shp  -nlt POLYGON -dim 3  import_polz.pol; ogrinfo -so -al export_pol.shp
```

In the DBF, the ID assignments (ID,N,9,0) are correctly transferred with 1 and 2006, 2016, etc.

However, the conversion to a DXF file fails because of the assignment of the attributes to the layers:

```
ogr2ogr  -f "DXF"  export_lin.dxf  -nlt LINESTRING -dim 3  import_polz.pol; ogrinfo -so -al export_lin.dxf
```

The response looks like this:

> ERROR 1: DXF layer does not support arbitrary field creation, field 'ID' not created.
> INFO: Open of `export_lin.dxf' using driver` DXF' successful.
> Layer name: entities
> Geometry: Unknown (any)
> Feature Count: 390
> Extent: (0.000000, 0.000000) - (150.000000, 20.000000)
> Layer SRS WKT:
> (unknown)
> Layer: String (0.0)
> PaperSpace: Integer(Boolean) (0.0)
> SubClasses: String (0.0)
> Linetype: String (0.0)
> EntityHandle: String (0.0)
> Text: String (0.0)

In the forum I could only find the ten year old hint that the DXF format is complicated:
[Errors when converting MapInfo .tab to .dxf](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19007/errors-when-converting-mapinfo-tab-to-dxf)

However, a newer version of ogr2ogr now seems to know how to assign layers:
https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/dxf.html#dxf-writer

However, I have no success with the instructions. Does anyone know how to assign the polygon ID to a DXF layer?

A solution with gdal or QGIS3 is desirable.

Comment: >"DXF layer does not support arbitrary field creation"



To my knowledge only the geometry can be converted. It is not possible to transfer attributes to a DXF.

Comment: The field 'ID' is probably a default value and is used by ogr2ogr for example in "export_lin.dbf". Source: [c](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/ogr/ogrsf_frmts/dxf/ogrdxfwriterlayer.cpp). "This is really a dummy as our fields are precreated."  But according to source the variable "poFeatureDefn" must be defined to address a layer. Apparently this is also possible via -sql statement: [converting-a-csv-to-dxf-using-ogr2ogr-from-the-command-line](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/196089/converting-a-csv-to-dxf-using-ogr2ogr-from-the-command-line). Is anyone familiar with this?

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem. This error message is more of a warning. The DXF should still be generated.

Comment: The geometric elements have an ID. Layers can be defined in a DXF. For example, in the image above, a color corresponds to an ID or a layer. The correct assignment of the ID to a layer in a DXF would solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to convert the ID column into a DXF layer, then you can use this code:

```
ogr2ogr -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT  ID as Layer,  geometry from import_polz" ^
        -f "DXF"  export_lin.dxf  -nlt LINESTRING -dim 3  import_polz.pol
```

Comment: That's great. Many thanks to Mike.

Answer (score 0):

With a "trick" it`s possible to combnine multiple fields (here: FID and BOTTOM_ELEVATION) from an original file to dxf-label, I do (with data from Oracle) like that:

```
ogr2ogr --config GDAL_DATA "X:\OSGeo4W64\share\gdal" -sql "SELECT geom,'LABEL(f:Arial,t:'||FID||BOTTOM_ELEVATION||')' AS OGR_STYLE from ww_manhole" -f "DXF" X:\OSGeo4W64\new_file10.dxf OCI:secret1/secret2@("DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST= (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = my_host )(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME =***))):WW_MANHOLE" -nlt POINT -a_srs EPSG:25832 -clipsrc 408148 5794500 408400 5794700 -mapFieldType Integer64=String
```